# How to pass a string to a local sever in java

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

I have created a local server and a client window to make them communicate with each other locally.

The server and the client both are created. My problem here is I need the client to enter words in the

JTextField and I want to pass this to the server. Now when ever I check the entered string, it shows

that the string has a NULL value.

This is my client code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyClientSide extends JFrame{


    public static String userFile;
    public static String entered = "";

    public static String host = "localhost";
    public static int port = 8080;
    public static Socket socket = null;



    public static DataOutputStream out = null; 

    public MyClientSide(){

        JLabel jlbl = new JLabel("File Name: ");
        final JTextField jtxt = new JTextField(20);
        JButton jbtn = new JButton("Upload to Server");
        JPanel jpnl = new JPanel();

        jbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 

            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {//Start of actionPerformed 

                entered = jtxt.getText();


            }

        });


        jpnl.add(jlbl);
        jpnl.add(jtxt);
        jpnl.add(jbtn);
        this.add(jpnl);

    }

    public MyClientSide(String error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        JLabel jlbl = new JLabel("Please connect to server");

        this.add(jlbl);
    }


    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String error = "Please connect to server";

        MyClientSide connectFrm = new MyClientSide();

        MyClientSide errorFrm = new MyClientSide(error);

        try {

            socket = new Socket(host,port);

            connectFrm.setTitle("File Transfer Client");
            connectFrm.setSize(500,80);
            connectFrm.setVisible(true);
            connectFrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


                    InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     
                    InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                   out.writeBytes(entered); /*Here is my problem. when I pass this to the server,
                                              The value is NULL. I need to pass a string from 
                                              JTextField*/

        }

        catch (IOException e) {

            errorFrm.setTitle("Error!!!!");
            errorFrm.setSize(200,100);
            errorFrm.setVisible(true);
            errorFrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            System.err.print("Please connect to server");

        }

    }



}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you aren't waiting for the upload button to be pressed!

You call

```
       connectFrm.setVisible(true);
       connectFrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

but in the same breath, you then go on to communicate with the server.
Remember that `setVisible` for a `JFrame` is not a blocking call. That is, it will go straight on to the next code without stopping, whether or not the dialog has been shown, whether or not the button is pressed.

You need to only communicate with the server once the button has been pressed.

i.e.

in your `actionPerformed` function:

```
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {//Start of actionPerformed 

            entered = jtxt.getText();
            sendToServer(entered);

        }
```

then make a function called `sendToServer`, which will be called only after the data has been inputted.
Put your `try/catch` block

```
   try {
        socket = new Socket(host,port);
        ..
```

inside this new function

Comment: Thanks. Let me try and I will reply soon.

Comment: The problem is I don't want to show the client window if the user is not connected to the server. In this case If I will make the connection in the SendToServer which will be called in the ActionPerfomed, then the client will be able to see the window before the connection.

Answer (score 1):

The `entered` `String` will not be `null` but rather an empty `String` which is the value with which it has been initialized. You are creating a `Socket` before the user has a chance to enter the `String`.

Since you're using Swing, the safest approach is to use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). When the user has entered new text and you can then perform the `Socket` upload action without blocking the `EDT`.

Comment: ok, But the problem here is I don't want to show the client window without the client connecting to the server.

Comment: You can of course create the `Socket` as you are currently doing but it is good housekeeping not to have a potential idle socket. Many firewalls/routers close the unused ports after some timeout. Attempting perform operations after this will throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use your suggestion and I will reply soon